# Valid string sequences in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Can anyone advise how to code up a JSON Schema document to describe a string that can be one of three possible sequences? Say a string "fruit" can be only the following: "apple", "bananna" or "coconut".

I was thinking it might be possible to use regex but not sure how to indicate the regex constraint in JSON Schema.

https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.6.1

Here is what I have so far:

```
{   
  "$id": "https://example.com/person.schema.json",   
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",   
  "title": "TestSession",   
  "type": "object",   
  "properties": {
    "fruit": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "only three legal possibilities: apple, banana, or coconut"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#enumerated-values?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That looks like the answer to me in case you'd like to post one officially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `enum` keyword for this.

> The value of this keyword MUST be an array.  This array SHOULD have
> at least one element.  Elements in the array SHOULD be unique.
>
> An instance validates successfully against this keyword if its
> value    is equal to one of the elements in this keyword's array
> value.
>
> Elements in the array might be of any type, including null.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.1.2

For example `"enum": [ "apple", "bananna", "coconut" ]`.